# How to factory reset ubuntu mate 16.10?

Tags: mate, 16.10, reset

So i want to sell my computer. However i need to factory reset it. How can i do this on startup? I want something such as a key that i press on startup and a menu appears with the option to factory reset. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't exist on Ubuntu. Just format and reinstall.